# Android Switch between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, switch-statement

what i'm trying to do is a home screen that stays for 5 seconds and goes to      activity1.When i click a button in activity1 leads me to activity2.I've tried many times to  click the button but no switching happens.
    homescreen (5 seconds)=Main_Activity
    Activity1=selectpets.java
    Activity2=fishtank.java

onclick listener seems the problem i don't know what's wrong with it

```
     Main Activity Code
package com.set.petshome;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button fButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Delay Code after 5 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen); //where <next> is you target      activity :)
                }
            }, 5000);   
    }
//Delay End
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now the Selectpets Code

```
package com.set.petshome;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
public class SelectPetsScreen extends Activity  {
    Button fButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen);

      //Button Fishtank Listener Start

        fButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

          //Listening to button event
           fButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Starting a new Intent
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  fishtank.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);

                }
            });     
        //Button Fishtank Listener End

    }
   }
```

Fishtank class code

```
package com.set.petshome;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class fishtank extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ftank);



        }

    }
```

by the way no errors in the application just no switching after clicking
    thank you very much

Comment: You are changing the `setContentView()`. This will not start your `SelectPetsScreen` Activity and hence You will never have the button click listener assigned to it. Because you are still in the `MainActivity` :)

Comment: Did you add second Activity to Manifest.xml? If yes, try to add to SelectPetsScreen: ` android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you aren't ever switching to the next `Activity`, just changing the `layout` of the current `Activity`

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen); //where <next> is you target      activity :)
                }
            }, 5000);
```

instead of `setContentView()` you need to use an `Intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectPetsScreen.this);
startActivity(i);
```

Since you aren't actually going to the next `Activity` (java file) your `onClick()` isn't set.

**Edit**

This is what you are doing

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button fButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Delay Code after 5 seconds
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen); //where <next> is you target      activity :)
            }
        }, 5000);   
}
```

This is what you should be doing. Notice the difference in the `run()` function

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button fButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Delay Code after 5 seconds
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectPetsScreen.this);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 5000);   
}
```

Comment: Yes i know i want to switch from activity1 to activity2 and homescreen changes to activity1 which you're talking about.the code you mentioned i know that's not changing the activity.take a look again you'll see that your code i already used it but not change activity1 to 2 :D

Comment: No, in your `MainActivity` you are not doing this. Look at my answer again. You are not using an `Intent` there to start the next `Activity` which is where your `onClickListener` is set. You are JUST changing the `layout` and not going to the `Activity`.

Comment: Now i get it but after changing the code System UI stops(crashes) on MainActivity

Comment: I can't tell you why without knowing what the error is. What's it say in the logcat for `Fatal Exception` and what is the first line that references your package after that?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing this.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Delay Code after 5 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen); //where <next> is you target      activity :)
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Google gives you the Intent mechanism for switching Activities

i.e. use

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, yourSecondActivity.class));
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen);
```

The remaining part of your code must work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `finish()` if you want use firts Activity only once.

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

 startActivity(new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, SelectPetsScreen .class).setData(getIntent().getData()));
        finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Be sure that you have 2nd Activity defined in your Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="x.x.SelectPetsScreen"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitle"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: @user1928775 Did you add second Activity to Manifest.xml?

Comment: @user1928775 try to add to SelectPetsScreen: in manifest.xml: ` android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: Thanks Maxim Shoustin and everyone it worked after adding SelectPetsScreen in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with the help of Maxim Shoustin and everyone by:
adding second Activity to Manifest.xml which is SelectPetsScreen
Thank you so much